# Problema al renderizar datos de un objeto json con React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Estoy practicando con un proyecto de React con Firebase. Necesito traer los datos de un json alojado en la realtime database de Firebase.

Está estructurado de esta manera: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi aplicación hay una sección donde se muestran todos los datos de "cupcakes" con esta petición GET: `https://cupcakes-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/cupcakes.json` la cual me devuelve un array con los datos del json dentro. Recorro el array con un .map() y funciona sin problemas.

El problema empieza cuando, en cierta parte de la página, quiero mostrar sólo unos cuantos cupcakes. Para ello utilizo la misma petición pero con un filtro: `https://cupcakes-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/cupcakes.json?orderBy="id"&startAt=3&endAt=6` la cual me produce un error cuando intento recorrerla con .map() *(error: cupcakes.map is not a function)*. Después de hacer unas pruebas me di cuenta que a diferencia de la petición sin filtro, esta no me devuelve los datos dentro de un array.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código que considero relevante de la aplicación (el código no es 100% mío, la mayor parte es una copia de un curso donde se realiza este proyecto).

Primero, un Hook propio que se encarga de hacer la peticion GET.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { get } from "axios"

const useFetch = (endpoint, filtro) => {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState()
    const [ error, setError ] = useState()

    useEffect(() =>{
        get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_API}${endpoint}.json${filtro}`)
            .then(({ data }) => setData(data))
            .catch(err => setError(err))
    }, [endpoint, filtro])

    return [data, error];
}

export default useFetch
```

Luego el componente que crea el cupcake.

```
import useFetch from "../../hooks/useFetch"
import Cupcake from "../cards/Cupcake"


const Cupcakes = ({ peticion, filtro, title }) => {
    const [cupcakes] = useFetch(peticion, filtro)
    console.log('datacupcakes:',cupcakes)
    return(
        <div>
            {title && <h1 className="ms-4">Página de cupcakes</h1>}
            {
                cup ? (
                    <section className="cupcakes-container">
                    {
                        cup.map(({id, descripcion, imagen, sabor, color, precio, vendido, numero}) => (
                            <Cupcake
                                key={id}
                                numero={numero}
                                imagen={imagen}
                                descripcion={descripcion}
                                sabor={sabor}
                                color={color}
                                precio={precio}
                                vendido={vendido}
                            />
                        ))
                    }
                </section>
                ) : (<span>Cargando...</span>)
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Cupcakes
```

Y finalmente la sección donde quiero que se rendericen los cupcakes filtrados.

```
import Servicios from "../sections/Servicios"
import Cupcake from "./cupcake"
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"

const query = '?orderBy="id"&startAt=3&endAt=6'

const Home = () =>{
    return(
        <>
<div className="main-banner">
    <div className="main-banner__info">
      <h1 className="">Bienvenido</h1>
      <p className="">Página de cupcakes con React.</p>
      <div className="banner-btn">
      <NavLink className="btn btn-danger" to="/cupcakes" exact>Ver Cupcakes</NavLink>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
            <Cupcake peticion="cupcakes" filtro={query}/>
            <Servicios peticion="servicios" filtro="?"/>
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

En teoría, el objeto que recibo con "useFetch" ya debería venir dentro de un array, pero sigue llegando sólo como objeto.

Lo ultimo que intenté fue crear una variable con un array vacío y luego hacerle un push con lo que que me devuelve "useFetch", pero tanto el objeto como el array se vuelven *undefined*

¿Alguna idea de como puedo solucionar esto sin cambiar demasiado la idea base del código?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que al aplicar el filtro, los resultados vienen en una estructura tipo `hash table/dictionary` con propiedades enumerables, que en Javascript se puede representar como un tipo `Object`:

```
Petición con filtro: {2:{...},3:{...},4:{...},5:{...}}
```

Por esta razón al tratar de iterar este tipo `Object`, con el método `map` propio del tipo `Array`, se obtiene:

> error: cupcakes.map is not a function

Una forma de solucionarlo es transformar la estructura de `data` para que sea un array de objects cuando se aplique el filtro, esta transformación se puede lograr con `Object.values`.

Esta es una propuesta, si se usa el mismo `useFetch` para ambas peticiones (con filtro/sin filtro) se deberá agregar la lógica correspondiente:

```
const useFetch = (endpoint, filtro) => {
    const [ data, setData ] = useState()
    const [ error, setError ] = useState()

    useEffect(() =>{
        get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_API}${endpoint}.json${filtro}`)
            .then(({ data }) => {
                     //aqui tal vez se necesite lógica para evaluar con o sin filtro
                     if(Array.isArray(data)){
                        setData(data);
                     } else {
                        const ObjectToArray = Object.values(data);
                        setData(ObjectToArray);
                     }
             }).catch(err => setError(err))
    }, [endpoint, filtro])

    return [data, error];
}
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Enlaces:

[Property accessors / associative arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

[Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

[isArray JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)